# Group by categorical column and by range of ids

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe similar to this one:

```
     col  inc_idx
0    A    1
1    B    1
2    C    1
3    A    2
4    A    3
5    B    2
6    D    1
7    E    1
8    F    1
9    F    2
10   Z    1
```

And I'm trying to iterate the df by batches:

First loop: All col rows with inc_idx >= 1 and inc_idx <=2

```
A 1
A 2
B 1
B 2
...
```

Second loop: All col rows with inc_idx >= 3 and inc_idx <=4

```
A 3
```

The way I'm doing it now leaves a lot of room for improvement:

```
i = 0
while True:
    for col, grouped_rows in df.groupby(by=['col']):
        from_idx = i * 2
        to_idx = from_idx + 2
        items = grouped_rows .iloc[from_idx:to_idx].to_list()
    i += 2
```

I think that there's got to be a more efficient approach and also a way to remove the "while True" loop and instead just waiting for the internal loop to run out of items.

Comment: Kindly post your expected output dataframe

Comment: I don't expect a dataframe but a way to iterate it in the way I described it, by chunking the group of cols using ther incremental idx's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found (I think) a simpler way to solve it. I'll add a new "batch" column:

```
df['batch'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['inc_idx'] // 2, axis=1)
```

With this new column, now I can simply do something like:

```
df.groupby(by=['col', 'batch'])
```

Comment: You need to add `1` to `inc_idx` if you want the odd number to be grouped with the next even number. As you have it `0,1` would be batch `0` and `2,3` would be batch `1` and so on.

Comment: That was an error when I wrote it initially, inc_idx starts at 0.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you want to do. Here's something that groups the rows.

```
df.groupby((df.inc_idx + 1) // 2).agg(list)
                                    col                         inc_idx
inc_idx                                                                
1        [A, B, C, A, B, D, E, F, F, Z]  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
2                                   [A]                             [3]
```

Comment: This looks good to me. here's how you could iterate through it (oops can't make newlines in comment)

```
for i,g in df.groupby((df.inc_idx + 1) // 2):
    print(f'Working with inc_idxs between {i*2-1} and {i*2}')
    print(g)
```